# How to modify TimelineLite timing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap

I’m quite new with the GreenSock and I got myself in trouble...

I would like to modify GreenSock TimelineLite timing offset for reverse so that some delays get deleted (I think that they are called staggers).

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/4bvnv1d5/

```
var red = $('.red');
var green = $('.green');
var blue = $('.blue');
var black = $('.black');

var tl = new TimelineLite({onReverseComplete:reverseCompleted});

$('#start').click(function(){
    tl.to(red, 0.3, {ease: Power1.easeInOut, 'margin-left':'100px'});
    tl.to(green, 0.3, {ease: Power1.easeInOut, 'margin-left':'100px'});
    tl.to(blue, 0.3, {ease: Power1.easeInOut, 'margin-left':'100px'});
    tl.to(black, 0.3, {ease: Power1.easeInOut, 'margin-left':'100px', onComplete:lastCompleted, onCompleteParams:[black]}, "+=4");
});

$('#reverse').click(function(){
    tl.reverse();    
});

function lastCompleted(target) {
    console.log('lastCompleted');    
}

function reverseCompleted(){
    console.log('reverseCompleted');
    tl.clear();
    tl.restart();
}
```

On play there is a four second delay with the last box, but on the reverse I’d like to animations to play right after each other with no delays. There is function lastCompleted() which is triggered after the last tween gets run. How can I use that function to remove the delay between the black and blue box animations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/t09ee1o1/)** fiddle.

**JavaScript:**

```
var red = $('.red');
var green = $('.green');
var blue = $('.blue');
var black = $('.black');

var tl = new TimelineLite({
    paused: true,
    callbackScope: this,
    onReverseComplete: onTlReverseComplete
});
tl.staggerTo([red, green, blue], 0.3, { marginLeft: 100, ease: Power1.easeInOut }, 0.3);
tl.addLabel('MyLabel');
tl.to(black, 0.3, { marginLeft: 100, ease: Power1.easeInOut, onReverseComplete: onBlackBoxReverseComplete, callbackScope: this }, '+=4');

$('#start').click(function () {
    tl.play();
});
$('#reverse').click(function () {
    tl.reverse();
});

function onBlackBoxReverseComplete() {
    tl.reverse('MyLabel');
}

function onTlReverseComplete() {
    tl.stop();
}
```

Quite a few things have changed from your code. Here is the list:

- The tweens are added into the `tl` instance outside the scope of click handler of `#start` button. The click handler only `.play()`s the timeline forward.
- `.staggerTo()` method is used instead of adding adding the 3 tweens one by one before the one for `.black` element.
- Also, `margin-left` has been replaced by its JS equivalent `marginLeft` and since it accepts numbers and defaults to pixels, no need to pass the values as strings.
- The tween for `.black` element has now a `onReverseComplete` callback.

Hope this helps. Let me know if you have any questions.